# Enable and disable check boxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

[Table with two checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyhbb.png)

I have a data table and it includes two check boxes called Manufacturing Defects and Scrap Items.I need to disable Scrap Items,when I check the Manufacturing Defects vise versa.
Please help me to find the answer.
Bellow is my code part, I used to create checkboxes

```
row += '<td class="Item_Rejected1">' + '<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="isActive()">' + '</td>';
row += '<td class="Item_Rejected2">' + '<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="isActive()">' + '</td>';
```

Comment: Here, disable means what ? you need to uncheck other one or disable ?

Comment: I'm sorry not the word disable. It is uncheck.

Comment: You should use a radio button for this.

Comment: FYI the accepted answer is the poorest one among all answers mixing jQuery selectors and native selectors with lots of unnecessary DOM queries and duplicate code... .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the actual answer as requested by Rasika. Dont change the questions. It is the answer for that one. I got output  .

[Here is the output] https://jsfiddle.net/Abhilash1994/btmfuwsg/

```
Manufacturer: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"> 
Scrap: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCheck').change(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                document.getElementById("myCheck1").disabled=true;
            }
            else {
               document.getElementById("myCheck1").disabled=false;
            }
        });
        $('#myCheck1').change(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled=true;
            }
            else {
               document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled=false;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote. It will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Detect click on any checkbox
(2) Uncheck ALL checkboxes
(3) Check the checkbox that was clicked

```js
/*  javascript/jQuery  */
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Item_Rejected1">
      IR1 <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
    <td class="Item_Rejected2">
      IR2 <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! It is working :)

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.not(SELECTOR)` to exclude current element

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Item_Rejected1">
      IR1
      <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
    <td class="Item_Rejected2">
      IR2
      <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You!! It is working :)

Answer (score 0):

One more answer,

```js
   

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if (this.checked)
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Item_Rejected1">
      IR1
      <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
    <td class="Item_Rejected2">
      IR2
      <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="checked" class="form-control input-sm">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```